# Change posts content font size?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress premium theme called "Sahifa". I want to change all the written posts content font size to 16px.

Here is my CSS:

```
.entry {line-height:1.5;}
    .content .entry iframe {max-width: 100%; }
    .entry p {padding-top: 1.0em; padding-bottom: 1.0em;}
    .entry img { max-width:100%; height:auto;}
    .entry h1, .entry h2, .entry h3, .entry h4, .entry h5, .entry h6 {
        margin-top: 25px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        line-height: 1em;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
        .entry h1 {font-size:36px;}
        .entry h2 {font-size:30px;}
        .entry h3 {font-size:24px;}
        .entry h4 {font-size:18px;}
        .entry h5 {font-size:14px;}
        .entry h6 {font-size:12px;}
    .entry ol,
    .entry ul {margin: 0 0 25px 10px;}
    .entry ul li {list-style: outside disc; list-style-type: disc; list-style-image: none; list-style-position: outside;}
    .entry ol li {list-style: outside decimal;}
        .entry li {margin: 0 0 5px 10px;}
```

Tell me please, what should i change.
Regards,
: )

Comment: How do you know the post font-size is 14px?

Answer (score 0):

Change the third line to:

```
.entry p {padding-top: 1.0em; padding-bottom: 1.0em; font-size: 16px;}
```

You may find it interesting to consider the different ways you can specify font sizes (you don't have to just use pixels - you can give it as a ratio of the current font-size), as in [this](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) article.

Comment: Nothing happened. Posts still with the same font-size.

Comment: It would be very useful to see some HTML to see which elements we need to target with the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is Click on Sahifa > Typography